# DLL Could not be found in the project folder

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I searched lot. There is huge questions are in SO. But its not clear my problem. In my project i added a reference via

> Reference->RightClick->Added Reference->Project->solution

But in my project folder it does not having the required DLL in

> Projectfolder->Bin->Release

How can i get that specified DLL in Project folder.

I'm facing error like that

**Metadata file:'Projectpath.dll'could not be found.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if needs DLL,Select the Project and goto the property window

[image]

Need to change project **Output Type** into **Class Library**

And onemore thing, Check your project **Solution Configuration**.

[image]

If it is in Debug mode means, DLL Should be in

> Projectfolder->Bin->Debug

Either it is in Release mode

> Projectfolder->Bin->Release

Answer (score 0):

Go to reference, click on that reference, right mouse button, properties -> "copy to output"

[image]

Comment: First: what is your bulid type? Debug or Release?

Comment: You mean Solution Configuration , Its Debug

Comment: If you want to have files in Projectfolder->Bin->Release you need to compile it in Release mode

Comment: Btw. I have added picture with "Copy Local" Properties.